# Pandas find datetime rows within a specified timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am trying to develop an algorithm that finds rows based on two criteria and assigns a value to these.

Basically I am looking to find the rows where a column is a value and which occurs greater than a specified timedelta from another value based on a datetime column

In a very simplified example below, find columns where the value is Dog and is greater than 1 minute from Cat and give them the new value Bear

```
DateTime         Value New Column
2015-10-25 00:00 Dog   Bear
2015-10-25 00:01 Dog   Dog
2015-10-25 00:02 Cat   Cat
2015-10-25 00:03 Dog   Bear
```

I can do the first part easily enough but at a complete loss with how to use the time delta acpect

```
timefilter = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
df.loc[df['Value'] == 'Dog'] = 'Bear'
```

Comment: I don't think you have given enough specifics on the rules. If the criteria is not met then is the `New Column` value the same as the `Value` column?  And shouldn't the last row be have 'Dog' as the value in New Column?

Comment: Sorry my bad trying to create a dummy example

Rules are should be change if value = Dog and is greater than timefilter before Value=Cat. If this isn't met then New Column = Value

Answer (score 0):

@user2956554 - I think the key component you're looking for is the `.shift()` functionality of pandas.  It will help you get the minute differential. Here's the quick code I put together:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['1/3/2015 00:00','1/3/2015 00:01','1/3/2015 00:02','1/3/2015 00:03'], 'value':['Dog','Dog','Cat','Dog']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], infer_datetime_format = True)
df['delta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] - df['time'].shift(1)).dt.minute

df['new_column'] = df['value']
df['new_column'][(df['delta'] >= 1) & (df['value'] == 'Dog') & (df['value'].shift(1) == 'Cat')] = 'Bear'
df.drop('delta', axis=1, inplace=True) # if you want to get rid of the 'delta' column
```

**Point of note:** pandas throws up a warning for the second to last line in my code based on the indexing style, but the code works.  The warning and reason behind it is a little above my pay-grade, but if you want to learn more, visit this link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy.

Here's the output (including the warning):

```
C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\pandas_time_test.py:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['new_column'][(df['delta'] >= 1) & (df['value'] == 'Dog') & (df['value'].shift(1) == 'Cat')] = 'Bear'
                 time value new_column
0 2015-01-03 00:00:00   Dog        Dog
1 2015-01-03 00:01:00   Dog        Dog
2 2015-01-03 00:02:00   Cat        Cat
3 2015-01-03 00:03:00   Dog       Bear
```